# Issue in expanding and collapsing tableview cell using swift 3 with Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to expand and collapse the table view cell by clicking them. I followed the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqHzHkuXRxQ&t=89s. Did all things exactly like in this video. It is successfully running without any error or warning. But i could not view the content in the table view cell. It just displays an empty table. I think it is Xcode version problem. In the tutorial, he used Xcode 7, i guess. And i'm using Xcode 8.2. I don't know what changes i should make, to view the content in the table view cell.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var selectedIndex = -1
    var dataArray : [[String:String]] = [["FirstName" : "Arun", "LastName" : "Gupta"],["FirstName" : "John", "LastName" : "Cena"],["FirstName" : "James" , "LastName" : "Bond"],["FirstName" : "Iron", "LastName" : "Man"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->CGFloat
    {
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            return 100;
        }
        else{
            return 40;
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! customCell
        let obj = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.firstViewLabel.text = obj["FirstName"]
        cell.secondViewLabel.text = obj["LastName"]
        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            selectedIndex = -1
        } else {
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}



import UIKit

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    var showsDetails = false {
        didSet {
            secondHeightConstraint.priority = showsDetails ? 250 : 999
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this link simple way to use https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

Comment: Thanks for the site. Its good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't supply `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

In your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: if i include UITableViewDataSource, it reports an error 'Type ViewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource'. but it accepts 'UITableViewDelegate' alone, and it shows the same empty table.

Comment: Note that, it is not included in the video too(Xcode 7). but it works!.

Answer (score 0):

If i see it correctly you are missing the `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` method. So your TableView have 0 sections.

Comment: It is not compulsory to implement numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int

Comment: I hade the same problem, with an empty table and implementing numberOfSections actually solved it. So i thought maybe it is the same here.

Comment: Now tried adding this function ' func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
    }' Still same result :(